# Difference between $\nabla T$ and $\nabla \cdot E$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Why is $\nabla T = (\frac{\delta T}{\delta x},\frac{\delta T}{\delta y},\frac{\delta T}{\delta z})$, but $\nabla \cdot E \neq (\frac{\delta E}{\delta x},\frac{\delta E}{\delta y},\frac{\delta E}{\delta z}) $
So what difference does the dot between the nabla and the letter make here? How about just $\nabla E $?  Is $\nabla E \neq (\frac{\delta E}{\delta x},\frac{\delta E}{\delta y},\frac{\delta E}{\delta z})$?

Answer (score 3):

T is a scaler quantity while E is a vector quantity.
$$\eqalign{
  & T = T(x,y,z)  \cr 
  & \nabla  = \left( {{\partial _x},{\partial _y},{\partial _z}} \right)  \cr 
  & E = \vec E = \left( {{E_x},{E_y},{E_z}} \right)  \cr 
  & \nabla T = \left( {{\partial _x}T,{\partial _y}T,{\partial _z}T} \right)  \cr 
  & \nabla  \bullet E = {\partial _x}{E_x} + {\partial _y}{E_y} + {\partial _z}{E_z} \cr} $$

Comment: But is $\nabla E \neq (\frac{\delta E}{\delta x},\frac{\delta E}{\delta y},\frac{\delta E}{\delta z})$?

Comment: I think $\nabla \cdot E $ is shorthand for divergence. $\nabla T$ a gradient vector but it's  been a long time.

Comment: $E$ is a vector field and the action of $\nabla\cdot$ on it is different from the action of $\nabla$ on a scalar field.

Comment: No, you can only multiply vectors using dot products and cross products.
$$\eqalign{
  & \nabla f = gradient\;of\;scaler  \cr 
  & \nabla  \bullet \vec E\; = \;divergence\;of\;a\;vector  \cr 
  & \nabla  \times \vec E = \;curl\;of\;a\;vector \cr} $$

Comment: @JakeLebovic So would just $\nabla E $ be impossible?

Comment: @Dirak -- No, technically It is not "impossible" to have the differential operator nabla act on a vector field such as $E$. However, the result would be a 3x3 tensor, i.e. an object consisting of 9 separate quantities.

Comment: @M.Wind  So what would this " a 3x3 tensor" for $\nabla \vec E$ look like?

Comment: The $x-$, $y-$ and $z-$ components of the vector field $E$, are each differentiated with respect to the three Cartesian coordinates $x$, $y$, $z$. The 9 resulting quantities are usually represented in a $3$ by $3$ matrix.

Comment: The tensor would look like this...
$$ \nabla \vec E = {\partial _i}{E_j} = {F_{ij}} = \left( {\matrix{
   {{F_{xx}}} & {{F_{xy}}} & {{F_{xz}}}  \cr 
   {{F_{yx}}} & {{F_{yy}}} & {{F_{yz}}}  \cr 
   {{F_{zx}}} & {{F_{zy}}} & {{F_{zz}}}  \cr 

 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   {{\partial _x}{E_x}} & {{\partial _x}{E_y}} & {{\partial _x}{E_z}}  \cr 
   {{\partial _y}{E_x}} & {{\partial _y}{E_y}} & {{\partial _y}{E_z}}  \cr 
   {{\partial _z}{E_x}} & {{\partial _z}{E_y}} & {{\partial _z}{E_z}}  \cr 

 } } \right)$$

Comment: @Jake Lebovic - Thank you. I tried to do this, but unfortunately my MathJax skills turned out to be insufficient for the job.

Answer (score 1):

for a scalar field $T, \nabla T$ represents the direction in which most of the change in $T$ will occur. for a vector field $E, \nabla \cdot E = div\ E$ represent the rate of change of flux of $E$ over a infinitesimal close surface to the volume. that is $$ dT = \nabla  T \cdot dx,\, div \, E = \nabla \cdot E = \frac{\int_S E.dS}{dV} $$

Answer (score 0):

The dot indicates a dot product. For instance, $(1,2) \cdot (3,4) = (1)(3) + (2)(4) = 3 + 8 = 11$.

So your two quantities live in different dimensional domains.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\vec{\triangledown} \cdot \vec{E}$ is taking a bit of a liberty with the mathematical 'del' operator and the dot product operation.

As you probably know, the dot product of two vectors is defined by:

$\vec{\mathbf{a}} = (a_{1}, a_{2}, ..., a_{n}) $ ; $\vec{\mathbf{b}} = (b_{1}, b_{2}, ..., b_{n}) $

$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ = $a_{1}b_{1} + a_2b_2 + ... + a_{n}b_{n} $

Furthermore the 'Del' operator is loosely defined as:

$\vec{\triangledown } = (\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{1}}, \frac{\delta }{\delta x_{2}}, ... , \frac{\delta }{\delta x_{n}})$

So, $\vec{\triangledown} \cdot \vec{E}$ can be interpreted to mean:

$ \frac{\delta }{\delta x_{1}}E_{1} + \frac{\delta }{\delta x_{2}}E_{2} + ... +\frac{\delta }{\delta x_{n}}E_{n}
    $

The key difference being that the result of this form is a scalar, while the typical gradient operator ($\vec{\triangledown} \vec{E}$) returns a vector. Also notice, as is pointed out in the comments earlier,  that the gradient operation produces a vector function in t variables when it acts on a scalar function of t variables, but the operation $\vec{\triangledown} \cdot \vec{F}$ always acts on a vector field which can be in any number of variables.